# js вытянуть значения ячеек Excel в переменные

Tags: javascript, mysql

Коллеги доброе время суток. Заинтересовался реализацией "js вытянуть значения ячеек Excel в переменные". 
1) Подгружаем на сайт файл excel со значениями(дабы не вводить вручную)
2) Пробегаемся по excel и присваиваем значения ячеек двумерному массиву mass

```
mass[i][i]= excel[i][i]
```

На примере поясню: допустим есть 2 критерия

```
(ячейка А1-"собака",ячейка B-1 "гав" ) 
(ячейка А2-"котик",ячейка B-2 "мяу" )
```

Посредствoм js подбираю нужную  комбинацию и играюсь. 
Искал инфу, пишут что вернее вносить полученные данные в MySQL, а дальше уже всё легче. Подскажите куда копать? Жизненная ли модель для работы сайта?

Comment: *Пробегаемся по excel и присваиваем значения ячеек двумерному массиву mass* Да можно использовать прямое присвоение диапазона в динамический массив... *пишут что вернее вносить полученные данные в MySQL* Правильно пишут - сайт с данными в Excel формате есть голимый бред... А СУБД может быть любая, необязательно MySQL.

Comment: Может кто еще подскажет?

Comment: @Akina Поправил,  хочу попросить ссылки на информацию о данной реализации, как-что-куда. Просто я со старта не понимаю с чего начать, этот файл нужно как-то закидывать на хостин, а каким средством указать на него и начать считывать? по средствам чего?

Comment: Из явакрипта обращаться к данным в формате Экселя? Под Windows вообще элементарно, DAO-OLEDB-ADO, выбирай не хочу... за никсы не скажу, не спец, но формат-то проприетарный, лучше сменить... а хоть бы и на CSV...